# phpass's custom base 64 encoder: does it have a name/advantage over Base64?

Tags: php, algorithm, encoding, base64, bit-manipulation

[phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) uses a strange (to me) algorithm in [encode64()](http://cvsweb.openwall.com/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/projects/phpass/PasswordHash.php?rev=1.8;content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup;only_with_tag=MAIN) to base 64 encode. [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Examples) and [Uuencode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuencoding#Formatting_Mechanism) linearly chunk 6 bits to produce each octet before mapping to a printable char.  `encode64` shuffles the bits around:

```
input bit location:    abcdefgh ijklmnop qrstuvwx
base64 bit location:   ..abcdef ..ghijkl ..mnopqr ..stuvwx
encode64 bit location: ..cdefgh ..mnopab ..wxijkl ..qrstuv
```

**Is this algorithm commonly known?** And besides backward compatibility, **why choose it over Base64**?

Below I've rewritten it to clarify the algorithm:

```
function encode64($input, $bytesToProcess)
{
    // convert to array of ints
    for ($i = 0; $i < $bytesToProcess; $i++) {
        $bytes[] = ord($input[$i]);
    }

    $octets = array();
    $i = 0;
    do {
        $value = $bytes[$i++];
        $octets[] = $value & 0x3f;
        if ($i < $bytesToProcess) {
            $value |= $bytes[$i] << 8;
        }
        $octets[] = ($value >> 6) & 0x3f;
        if ($i++ >= $bytesToProcess) {
            break;
        }
        if ($i < $bytesToProcess) {
            $value |= $bytes[$i] << 16;
        }
        $octets[] = ($value >> 12) & 0x3f;
        if ($i++ >= $bytesToProcess) {
            break;
        }
        $octets[] = ($value >> 18) & 0x3f;
    } while ($i < $bytesToProcess);

    return array_map(function ($i) {
        return str_pad(base_convert($i, 10, 2), 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }, $octets);
}

var_export(encode64("Man", 3));
```

(updated to indicate exactly where each input bit is moved)

Comment: [Drupal's port](http://drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x:/includes/password.inc#l46) describes this as "the *nix standard from crypt()"

Comment: Thank you for this question! I have tried to implement a Drupal compatible authentication in Go and use this package for base64 encoding: https://golang.org/src/encoding/base64/base64.go
But with result that created and in Drupal saved hashes don't matches. Only after reimplementing Go's base64-package, where I do this strange bit shifting like in Drupals base64Encode() the hashes matched. 
The question is, why Drupal or phpass developer do base64 encoding a special way. Really mistake? I will ask the question in Drupal Stackexchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`encode64()` just looks like an implementation of standard base64 which counts bits in the reverse order and uses a different character set -- if you squint your eyes the right way, it's selecting the *last* 6 bits of the first byte for the first output character, for instance. This is probably just a mistake; there's no security or performance benefit in doing it this way (and some performance drawbacks relative to PHP's native [`base64_encode`](http://php.net/base64_encode)).

Comment: It looks to me like it's doing a byte swap on both ends:  Reverse the order of the 3 input bytes, chunk them into 6 bit pieces, then reverse the order of the output bytes.

Comment: I think that'd have the same effect, yeah. Either way it's a reversal at some point in the process.

Answer (score 0):

encode64 uses '.' and '/' beside a-zA-Z0-9. Base64 uses '+' and '/'. Also '.'and '/' map to 0 and 1, while '+' and '/' map to 62 and 63 in Base64.

UUencode uses letters, digits, and many punctuation characters to be compatible with systems without capitals.

I'm not familiar with encode64. The only reason for using it would be if '+' is not allowed in the environment that you use. But then you could just use Base64 and do a str_replace.